# Windows phone 8 tilt effect not Working on grid

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am trying to put tilt efffect on grid or rectangle or border but the effect is not working.I have used xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"

and for grid

there is no effect after running the application.
I want to know on which controls we can use Tilt effect.Kindly help as I am new to windows phone development.Thanks in advance.

Comment: for grid the code is:   <Grid toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="183,344,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Background="Black"/>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tilt within the WP Toolkit only works for "Selectable" items. A Grid is not Selectable by itself. The Toolkit is built to only tilt a few elements. You can make this work my [Enabling tilt on non-selectable items](http://visuallylocated.com/post/2012/04/23/Enabling-tilt-on-non-selectable-items.aspx).

The short of it is to either fork the toolkit and change the code, or wrap your element by a supported "selectable" item.

Comment: thanks for the reply it worked for single grid.I have 6 grids with rectangle,image and textblock inside it.so for that I can put all grids inside one listboxitem?

Comment: If you want all grids to tilt together. If you want them to tilt separately, put them each in a ListBoxItem, or just a ListBox to wrap them all. It's ok to use a ListBox if you will be showing a lot of items that can be "selected"

Comment: Thank you sir.One more doubt i have if I am using seperate listboxitem for each grid then only the last grid tap event is working.Why is this problem coming I am not getting.